# Replacing data fields with code in JSON.stringify?

Tags: json, replace, stringify

So you can replace a property with a number, string, array, or object in JSON.stringify, like so:

```
var myObj = {
    'allstar': aFunction;
}

function myReplacer(key, value) {
    if(key === 'allstar') {
        return 'newFunction()';
    }
}
JSON.stringify(myObj, myReplacer); //returns '{"allstar": "newFunction()"}'
```

But can you change it so that it instead returns `'{"allstar": newFunction()}'` (without the quotes around `newFunction`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@derpirscher provided a very good answer that will probably get more upvotes than this one, but this is my preferred answer:

Based on derpirscher's answer I decided it would be easier to make my own version of JSON.stringify that allows you to replace properties with your own source code, and changed the name of the module so that there is no naming conflict with JSON.

It's on my github account:
https://github.com/johnlarson/xerxes

Answer (score 0):

I assume `typeof aFunction == "function"`? If so, even `JSON.stringify(myObj)` will not do what you want it to do, but return `'{}'` i.e. an object without properties, because functions are not supported in JSON.

Your desired result is not even valid JSON. `newFunction()` without quotes is not a supported value (string, number, array, object, boolean, null).

Edit: you could try to return `newfunction.toString()` in your replacer, which should deliver your function's source as string. When converting the JSON back, you then must `eval()` this string to get the actual function.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'm just looking for something that will turn my object into javascript code, and I was hoping I could repurpose JSON for that.